# Org.postgresql.util.PSQLException :

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

I'm using Kolten with PostgreSql I'm trying to establish Connection through JDBC.  with fun main the connection is Ok but with the main activity causes this Error "Org.postgresql.util.PSQLException : Something unusal has occurred to cause the driver to fail please report the exception"

Comment: Don't ask us, tell the Kotlin developers like they ask you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that while connecting to PostgreSQL via JDBC in your main activity, you're running across a PSQLException with a generic error message. In order to troubleshoot, make sure you are using the correct version of the JDBC driver, verify the connection URL,confirm the connection properties, check that the database server is reachable, register the driver, and go over error logging for further information. See the server logs for further information. If problems continue, send over pertinent code snippets for more help.
Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: Connection is already established with the  code in main function  fun main(args: Array<String>) {>>> connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);

Comment: is there is some thing related to User permition